# Uniqueness of Quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a group $G = S_3$ and a subgroup $H$ and I found the left cosets for all $g \in G$, and I want to find the quotient group $G/H$... is there a unique set for the quotient group? For example, I found one I know to be correct: $G/H = \{H, (1,2)H\}$ but in reality can't I use $G/H = \{H, (1,3)H\}$ or $G/H = \{H, (2,3)H\}$ as well?

This is my question.

I believe that it does not matter and the quotient group is not unique in the sense that there is more than one variation, but the key is to be consistent in the usage of expressing quotient group. 
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

These are all the same set, since $(1\ 2)H=(1\ 3)H=(2\ 3)H$. The quotient group *is* unique, but the cosets can usually be represented in several different ways. For example, when we take the quotient of $\mathbb Z$ by $2\mathbb Z$, we could view the cosets as either $\{2\mathbb Z, 2\mathbb Z + 1\}$ or $\{2\mathbb Z, 2\mathbb Z + 3\}$, but it's the same thing.

Comment: is it a coincidence that (1,2)H (1,3)H and (2,3)H using the elements (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3) are NOT in H and produce the quotient group when finding their cosets?

Comment: @IbrahimChalhoub I'm not sure I understand the question. If $h\in H$ then $hH=H$. More generally, if $a$ and $b$ are in the same coset of $H$, then $aH=bH$.

Comment: apologies - what I am trying to say is we know that we are using the elements (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3) to form a quotient group when "multiplied" by H. Is it pure coincidence that (1,2), (1,3), (2,3) are not members of H?